# What does tr -d [=,=] do?

Tags: bash, shell, sh, tr

I have a code example and there seems to be a piece of extra formatting tacked onto the end of some text processing:

```
tr -d [=,=]
```

I don't know what this does and the man page for `tr` is of little help.  Any insight on what this does?

Comment: BTW, the expression should be quoted to be safe -- as `'[=,=]'` -- otherwise the shell can replace it with a filename as a glob result (should you have a file named `,`, for example) before invoking `tr`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the `man tr` page,

> [=equiv=]
>
> Equivalence classes
>
> The syntax `[=C=]` expands to all of the characters that are equivalent to `C`, in no particular order. Equivalence classes are a relatively recent invention intended to support non-English alphabets. But there seems to be no standard way to define them or determine their contents. Therefore, they are not fully implemented in `GNU tr`; each character's equivalence class consists only of that character, which is of no particular use.

An example from the [`POSIX tr`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/utilities/tr.html) page

This example uses an equivalence class to identify accented variants  of the base character `'e'` in file1, which are stripped of [diacritical marks (WikiLink)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic)  and written to file2.

```
tr "[=e=]" "[e*]" <file1 >file2
```

i.e. if in file1 if `e` is represented as accented (either a `é` or `è`), they are treated as normal `e`

Comment: More interestingly, I wonder what characters are considered eqiuvalent to a comma in this case :)

Comment: @chepner: Yup searched around to see possible usages of syntax, could't find much about, it. Or more generally there was really scarce information on equivalence class. You know of some? would be happy to update here.

Comment: It could just be an equivalence class of one. For fun, I tried `echo "?;" | tr -d '[=?=]'`, but the second character, U+037E GREEK QUESTION MARK, wasn't removed. It's probably I need a locale where such equivalence classes are defined, and I simply am not using such a locale.

Comment: @chepner: exactly, `LC_COLLATE` for that matter, from the `POSIX` page,  `Represents all characters or collating elements belonging to the same equivalence class as equiv, as defined by the current setting of the LC_COLLATE locale category.`

Answer (score -3):

It will just remove the comma between the `==`. check below output.

```
%_Host@User> echo "1==,==2==,==3=,=4=,=5" | tr -d [=,=]
1====2====3==4==5
%_Host@User>
```

thanks.

Comment: That doesn't explain `echo "1,2,3,4,5" | tr -d [=,=]`.

Comment: `tr` evaluates each character independently of its context. Surrounding content has no impact whatsoever on behavior.