# What the mean of [=c=] and [.symbol.] in Bash?

Tags: regex, bash

I'm looking for the mean of "[=c=]" and "[.symbol.]" 
in Bash and some examples.

Thanks.

The subject "[Bash - what does tr -d [=,=] do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42303902/bash-what-does-tr-d-do)" does not answer my question because it has a very light response about "[=c=]", and there isn't response about "[.symbol.]".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash - what does tr -d \[=,=\] do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42303902/bash-what-does-tr-d-do)

Comment: More about `equivalence classes`here http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/regex.7.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both have to do with collation.

But, what is collation?

It is the way that characters get sorted, many times as a dictionary would sort them.

What that means is different for different languages. Some languages do not have accented letters and use only ASCII letters. For those, the ASCII number of a character is enough and characters are sorted by their ASCII value (avoiding control characters 0-31 and 127):

```
$ printf '%b' "$(printf '\\U%x' {32..126})"; echo
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

However, things are never so simple.
How should a `C` and a `c` be sorted in a dictionary?
Most of the times the answer is: together.
Think about it, where are you going to seek for the word `Canada`?
Inside the entry for `c`?
Yes, that makes sense, doesn't it?

## [= =]

And that is what sets the start for "equivalent" characters.
Of course `c` is equivalent to `c`:

```
$ [[ c =~ [[=c=]] ]] && echo "yes" || echo "no"
yes
```

And `d` is not equivalent to c:

```
$ [[ d =~ [[=c=]] ]] && echo "yes" || echo "no"
no
```

In many cases, C is also equivalent to c:

```
$ [[ C =~ [[=c=]] ]] && echo "yes" || echo "no"
yes
```

but, again, not so simple: Not in all languages:

```
$ LC_COLLATE=C ; [[ C =~ [[=c=]] ]] && echo "yes" || echo "no"
no
```

In Germany, the umlaut 'ü' should collate to `u`:

```
$ LC_COLLATE=de_DE.UTF8; [[ ü =~ [[=u=]] ]] && echo "yes" || echo "no"
yes
```

Which also happens in English:

```
$ LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF8; [[ ü =~ [[=u=]] ]] && echo "yes" || echo "no"
yes
```

It seems also reasonable that all accented characters with `e` as a base:

```
é è ê ë ề ḕ É È Ê Ë Ề Ḕ
```

should collate together. That is what UNICODE does.

## [. .]

The concept of a `[.….]` has to do with [digraphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraph_%28orthography%29). In which, some double letters represent an unique sound, and, in some languages, such double letters act as an additional letter:

> Collating Symbols
>                A  collating  symbol is a multi-character collating
>                element enclosed in [.  and .].  For example, if ch
>                is a collating element, then [[.ch.]]  is a regular
>                expression that  matches  this  collating  element,
>                while  [ch]  is  a  regular expression that matches
>                either c or h.

The USA Spanish locale still retains the old collating symbol for `ll`:

```
$ LC_COLLATE=es_US.UTF8; [[ olla =~ [[.ll.]] ]] && echo "yes" || echo "no"
yes
```

But Spain has (long ago) removed such use:

```
$ LC_COLLATE=es_ES.UTF8; [[ olla =~ [[.ll.]] ]] && echo "yes" || echo "no"
no
```

Other countries will sure have other rules.